# Get result from call that doesn't return result?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, callable, futuretask

I'm using an API that makes calls for results, but doesn't return the result itself. Once the call is made, a separate method (a listener) is invoked, which contains the result. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Object obj = someMethod();

    System.out.println("The object is" + obj + ", wooh!");
}

public void callObject() {
    // This is the call that sends a request for the object
}

public void receiveObject(Object object) {
    // This is the API method that is invoked with the result (cannot be changed)
}

// What I want to be able to do
public Object someMethod() {
    callObject();
    // return received object once received, but how?
}
```

The callObject() doesn't return an object, only initiates the retrieval of it. I want to have a method that calls for the object, then returns it when it has been received. I've been looking into Callables and Future results, but I'm not sure how to implement them.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Is this supposed to be non-blocking? One common solution is to pass a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) object to the `callObject` method.

Comment: @Perdomoff I'll make an edit, bear with me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's non-blocking in the sense that other tasks should be able to run at the same time (separate thread), but references can be made to the result while it awaits for a result (e.g. the System.out.println)

Comment: Naturally in order to return an `Object` that is fetched by `callObject()`, `callObject()` would also need to return an `Object`. Then `someMethod()` could simply use `return callObject();` unless you need to perform other operations first.

Comment: @CalvinP. I just made an edit, but callObject doesn't actually fetch an object, only requests for an object to be received. The object is then later received in receiveObject().

Comment: are you allowed to override that `receiveObject` method?

Comment: @Mil4n Yeah that's how it's implemented, I can do what I want with the method.

Comment: So someMethod() is supposed to be blocking?

Comment: @ZeroOne Yeah explained myself badly, it is.

Comment: Also, can you have multiple threads calling callObject() or someMethod(), or can there only ever exist one single call that's in progress simultaneously?

Comment: @ZeroOne Needs to run simultaneously with other calls, but each one should be blocking - if that makes sense.

Comment: And do all the calls to the API return a different result? You may not use an API call result recently initiated by some other thread?

Comment: @ZeroOne The API returns different results, but in the order that the call was made.

Comment: So, did you manage to solve your problem? If you did, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203917) that you think was the best one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest case: you send your request in an ordinary blocking way and want to be able to do something on the main thread while it's being performed. For that, use [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), usually created by a call to [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), e.g.:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ToyConc1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        try {
            Callable<String> op1 = new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    return slowlyGetHttpPage("http://www.google.com");
                }
            }; 
            Callable<String> op2 = new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    return slowlyGetHttpPage("http://edition.cnn.com/");
                }
            }; 
            Future<String> resF1 = exec.submit(op1);
            Future<String> resF2 = exec.submit(op2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                System.out.println("doing useful work on the main thread...");
            }
            System.out.println("The object 1 is " + limit(resF1.get(), 1000) + ", wooh!");
            System.out.println("The object 2 is " + limit(resF2.get(), 1000) + ", wooh!");
        } finally {
            exec.shutdown();
            exec.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    private static String slowlyGetHttpPage(String urlName) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        URL url = new URL(urlName);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in); // wrong charset maybe
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    private static String limit(String s, int length) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (s.length() <= length) {
            return s;
        }
        return s.substring(0, length) + " [and " + (s.length() - length) + " more]";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the library/framework/technique that you use for sending the request and returning the result might already give you something like a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) or accept something like a callback (e.g. [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) does both).

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Introduce a new field into your class:

```
private Object result;
```

Then in the receiveObject(Object object) method you set it:

```
this.result = object;
```

In someMethod():

```
callObject();
while(this.result==null) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
Object answer = this.result;
this.result = null;
return answer;
```

Should work fine, as long as you create a new instance of this class for each API request. Don't try to make this class a singleton, it's just going to make things unnecessarily complicated.

Should you really require a singleton, you could generalize that `private Object result;` into a map and think of a way to identify each separate API call, like with some caller id.

Finally, you could also replace the `private Object result;` with a [java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Then complete that future in the `receiveObject` method and wait for it (`.get()` it) in `someMethod`. That would be a little more idiomatic than using a thread sleep loop.

Answer (score -1):

How it is possible that return something which there is nothing to be returned, int the `someMethod()` where is the `return` word, and `callObject()` return nothing because it is `void`. In this way it will return an object

```
public Object someMethod() {
    return new Object();
}
```